# Duplicate map in collection based on value in specific key

Tags: clojure

So I have this:

```
[{:a ["x" "y"], :b "foo"}
 {:a ["x" "y" "z"], :b "bar"}]
```

And want this:

```
[{:a "x", :b "foo"} 
 {:a "y", :b "foo"} 
 {:a "x", :b "bar"}
 {:a "y", :b "bar"}
 {:a "z", :b "bar"}]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` is really nice for known levels of nesting:

```
(for [x [{:a ["x" "y"], :b "foo"}
         {:a ["x" "y" "z"], :b "bar"}]
      a (:a x)] 
  (assoc x :a a))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mapcat`:

```
(def c [{:a ["x" "y"], :b "foo"}
        {:a ["x" "y" "z"], :b "bar"}])

(mapcat (fn [{:keys [a] :as m}] (map #(assoc m :a %) a)) c)
```